# Restoring fstab file on a Dell laptop

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, dell, fstab

I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS on Dell Inspiron 7577. Something went wrong and it appears that the fstab file became corrupt. Sadly, I didn't make its backup. Now the top menu and the launcher don't load upon booting. My hard drive is partitioned into four pieces:

```
sda1 EFI system partition fat32, flags: boot,esp
sda2 Basic data partition fat32, flags: msftdata
sda3 ext4
sda4 linux-swap
```

*sda1* is mounted as */boot/efi/* and *sda3* as */* . This information is from **gparted**. The content of my current fstab file follows:

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/ was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=64ef968d-8488-49b1-8dde-a0829168b76f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0     1
/boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0AEC-8283  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0     1
swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=181a3feb-93f6-4e98-8583-52a683f658bc none            swap    sw    0       0
```

I think I can make my system operational by manually editing fstab. However, I want to roll back to the default settings. Rolling everything back to the factory settings is not an option for me. I only want the original fstab and partitions back.

**Can I find somewhere the default fstab file which was shipped with my laptop?**

Another thing which puzzles me is that *sda2* is set to be mounted at startup in the **gnome-disks** utility. Why is it not mounted in the end then? **nautilus** also knows about my original partitions, which were before the corruption of fstab. Can I just copy the mounting settings from **gnome-disks** to fstab? Are these settings the same as remembered by **nautilus**?

Comment: Try booting with a live-usb, installing boot-repair and running it.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to Ubuntu. Is boot-repair another piece of software? I think my problem was caused by using, perhaps incorrectly, ddrescue. I am really seeking a low-level advice to repair the problem by hand. Yes, I think I can format HDD and install Ubuntu anew. This is not a solution I am looking for.

Comment: [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) doesn't reformat HDD but it rebuilds `fstab` and `grub`.

Comment: Thank you, but I still think it would be an overkill. I do have access to Ubuntu. It boots. I can launch the terminal, launch any programs I want. Only Unity does not launch and those partitions which used to be mounted automatically, don't do this anymore.

Comment: I can mount them by hand though. I think I can edit **fstab** manually too. But is my current **fstab** copied above not already the default one? I don't remember changing it when I just bought the laptop. The only thing I did was to partition my HDD. After that it was mounted automatically at every boot. I think I broke somethink by running **ddrescue**. But I don't know what.

Comment: I ran this: **ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb4 logfile**

Comment: _/dev/sdc1_ was a corrupt flash drive and _/dev/sdb4_ was a HDD partition. Both devices were mounted at the time I ran that. As a result, _/dev/sdb4_ was repatitioned. I think that after that all other partitions became unmounted and stopped mounting at boot.

Comment: Trying boot repair is an easy first step. If that doesn't work then you could proceed with more complicated and possibly destructive methods. I haven't used `ddrescue` myself so can't comment on it.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I hesitate proceeding with boot-repair. I checked the files in _/etc/_ which were modified around the time the problem appeared and fstab was not among them. The only suspicious files there which _were_ modified are _/etc/init.d/.depend.boot_ , _.depend.stop_ , _.depend.start_ and _/etc/mailcap_ . I don't know if they are responsible for this issue.

Comment: Boot repair runs a report of problems with option to fix.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you! I did update + upgrade and now Unity loads! I have no clue why it did not load before. Perhaps some bug. Anyway, now Unity loads, yet the main problem persists: my partitions do not mount at boot. I can click on them in nautilus and mount with no problem, but this is not what I used to do. I also see those big "unmount" arrows next to each partition in nautilus.

Comment: Would you still suggest using boot-repair to identify the reason why the partitions are not mounted at startup?

Comment: Boot repair report won't hurt and might help. It only takes a few  minutes to download, install and run.